# Default create-react-app does not work in IE despite polyfills and browser list

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer

Am on the simple quest to get create-react-app working in IE 11. I am working from Mac OS X and I cannot get IE 11 working either through VirtualBox or through a Windows computer (both in dev and production mode).

I have investigated this thoroughly, and tried the following:

- Adjusted package.json as per the below, then (i) removed node_modules/.cache, then when that didn't work, (ii) removed node_modules

```html
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie 11"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  }
```

- Added these two lines to the top of my index.js file:

```js
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

- Installed @babel/polyfill and inserted this line at the top of index.js

```html
import "@babel/polyfill";
```

All of this is with the default app created by create-react-app. No luck, and all I get in IE is a completely blank screen with "React App" as the title. The F12 Developer tools give the below errors:

[image: Error messages in IE 11]

Any help on this greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what IE thinks the SyntaxError is? Can you click into that to see the code producing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is related to the react-scripts version, you are using react-scripts 3.3.0 and higher. You could check the package.json file to verify it.

There are some thread reports this error in GitHub, you could refer to them, for example: [github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197](http://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197), [github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195](http://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195).

As a workaround, you could try to downgrade the react-scripts version. As far as I know, it can still work with `react-scripts@3.2.0`.