# How to use Create-React-App with Internet Explorer 10 or better

Tags: internet-explorer, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I am using create-react-app to develop code for a corporate intranet.  It is a Microsoft based system so using IE is essential.  Unfortunately nothing I have tried is able to allow me to load it in Internet Exploder.

Here is my package.json file.  Let me know if other files are required.  My familiarity with Babel and webpack is non-existent unfortunately so I need all the help I can get on this.

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.20.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-nested-menu": "^1.0.9",
    "react-popper": "^1.3.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-redux-form": "^1.16.14",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && xcopy /E /Q /H /Y build c:\\inetpub\\ReactFrontEnd",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "ie 11",
      "ie 10"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:81/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3"
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to search for this issue and found that recently there is some issue with **"react-scripts": "3.3.0"** because of this project is not working with IE browser.

I suggest you try to use **"react-scripts": "3.2.0"**. It can help to fix this issue.

Try to clear node_modules/.cache after making this change.

References:

1. [Default create-react-app does not work in IE despite polyfills and browser list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59784600/default-create-react-app-does-not-work-in-ie-despite-polyfills-and-browser-list)
2. [“react-app-polyfill” doesn't work in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59834690/react-app-polyfill-doesnt-work-in-ie11)
3. [IE11 support doesn't work in dev mode, even after adding all polyfills and enabling ie11 support #8197](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197)
4. [Why application created using create-react-app is not working in IE browser? #8195](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195)