# Why React app is not working in Internet Explorer browser

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, webpack, create-react-app, polyfills

React App is not Working in internet explorer at all, i have used multiple solution for this issue but not got any solution.

1. npm i react-app-polyfill --save
2. add below files in index.js

   import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
       import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
       import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
3. In package.json and add "ie 11" into "browserslist->development" section:

*

```
"browserslist": {
"production": [
">0.2%",
"not dead",
"not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
"ie 11",
"last 1 chrome version",
"last 1 firefox version",
"last 1 safari version"
]
}
```

4. delete .cache in node_modules
5. npm start

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open the package.json file and check whether you are using **"react-scripts": "3.3.0"** or greater?

I have seen many users are having similar issues nowadays.

If you are using **"react-scripts": "3.3.0"** or greater then try to use **"react-scripts": "3.2.0"**. It can help to fix this issue.

Try to clear node_modules/.cache after making this change.

References:

1. [Default create-react-app does not work in IE despite polyfills and browser list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59784600/default-create-react-app-does-not-work-in-ie-despite-polyfills-and-browser-list)
2. [“react-app-polyfill” doesn't work in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59834690/react-app-polyfill-doesnt-work-in-ie11)
3. [IE11 support doesn't work in dev mode, even after adding all polyfills and enabling ie11 support #8197](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197)
4. [Why application created using create-react-app is not working in IE browser? #8195](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195)

Comment: Hi @deepak-MSFT I am using "react-scripts": "3.2.0" only , Still its not working

Comment: try to create a new app and try to use "react-scripts": "3.2.0" to check whether that project is working or not. It can be a cache issue with your current app.